# Diophantine equation with perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all the integer solutions of the equation:
>   $$(n^2-4)n = 3b^2$$

#### Progress

I tried casework based on what $n$ is modulo $3$ but it didn't work.

Comment: What have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried casework based on what n is modulo 3 but it didn't work.

Comment: Try considering that the LHS is $(n-2)n(n+2)$ and that $(n-2),n,(n+2)$ are "almost coprime". Since the RHS is three times a square, $(n-2),n,(n+2)$ are all a square, twice a square, three times a square or six times a square. But they are too close to allow this too many times.

Comment: First, $n$ must a multiple of $3$ in order for $n(n+2)(n-2)/3$ to be an integer. So, replace $n$ with $3n$ to get $$(9n^2-4)n = b^2$$ This is just to start...

Comment: @DerekOrr Unfortunately this is not correct, the LHS expression is always divisible by 3 no matter what n is.

Comment: @pickasu Oops I made a dumb mistake in the program I used. You're right.

Comment: Advice for the future: most readers appreciate an indication of own work/thought much more than meaningless "Thanks so much!".

Answer (score 0):

$$n(n^2-4)=3b^2$$

- $n=\pm 2$,we have the solution $(n,b)=(\pm2,0)$
- $n^2>4$ ,then:
  if $n$ is odd,then:

$$(n,n^2-4)=1$$

So,there are integers $k,l$, such that:
$$n=k^2 ,n^2-4=3l^2 $$

or

$$n=3k^2, n^2-4=l^2$$

At the second system,the only solution is $l=0$,so $n^2=4$(We have already seen this solution)

For the first system:

$$n=k^2 , n^2-4=3l^2 , n \text{ odd } $$

$$n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$$
$$n^2-4 \equiv 5 \pmod8, \text{ so } 3l^2 \equiv 5 \pmod 8 \text{that is impossible}.$$

We have shown that if  $n$ is odd,we don't have solutions.

Now check the case,when $n$ is even.

Comment: What this is wrong.
By instance take $n=3$ we need to have $15 = 3b^2$, so $b = \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @pickasu I edited my post..

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is an odd prime and $p \mid b$, then $p$ divides exactly one of $n, n-2, n+2$. Hence, in order for the equation to hold, we must have $p^2$ dividing one of those three.

If $n$ is odd, that means we must have $3$ consecutive odd numbers, two of which are square, and one of the form $3k^2$. Since there are no square numbers that are $2$ or $4$ apart, this is impossible.

Can you show using similar reasoning that if $n$ is even, there are no solutions?